# How to count number of Audio/Subtitle Tracks in given AVURLAsset in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, http-live-streaming, avasset

I want to count the number of audio and subtitle tracks in given AVURLAsset. How do I do that using Swift ?

For given manifest expected answer should be 2 subtitles and 3 audio tracks

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subtitle",NAME="#1 Fre",DEFAULT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="fre",URI="subtitles/planete_interdite_subtitle3_fre_vtt.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subtitle",NAME="#3 Eng",DEFAULT=NO,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="eng",URI="subtitles/planete_interdite_subtitle5_eng_vtt.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="hdready",NAME="#2 Eng",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="eng",URI="hdready/planete_interdite_4160_n264_720p_audio2_eng.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="fullhd",NAME="#1 Fre",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="fre",URI="fullhd/planete_interdite_8256_n264_1080p_audio1_fre.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="fullhd",NAME="#2 Eng",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="eng",URI="fullhd/planete_interdite_8256_n264_1080p_audio2_eng.m3u8"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=314000,CODECS="avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=256x144,AUDIO="low",SUBTITLES="subtitle"low/planete_interdite_228_h264_144p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=638000,CODECS="avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=426x240,AUDIO="medium",SUBTITLES="subtitle"medium/planete_interdite_500_h264_240p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1942000,CODECS="avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x360,AUDIO="high",SUBTITLES="subtitle"high/planete_interdite_1228_q264_360p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=3274000,CODECS="avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=854x480,AUDIO="veryhigh",SUBTITLES="subtitle"veryhigh/planete_interdite_2080_q264_480p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=4814000,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720,AUDIO="hdready",SUBTITLES="subtitle"hdready/planete_interdite_4160_n264_720p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=9501000,CODECS="avc1.640028,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1920x1080,AUDIO="fullhd",SUBTITLES="subtitle"fullhd/planete_interdite_8256_n264_1080p.m3u8
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

< /Hey >

It looks like you will need to be using the function [AVAsset.tracks()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasset/1387140-tracks) :

```
func tracks(withMediaType mediaType: AVMediaType) -> [AVAssetTrack]
```

Then you can specify the `mediaType` argument out of the selection they provide [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmediatype). From what you can specify, it looks like you will have to use `AVMediaType.audio` & `AVMediaType.subtitle`.

i.e. To get the number of audio tracks

```
var audioTracks = YourAVURLAsset.tracks(AVMediaType.audio);
var nAudioTracks = audioTracks.count;
```

or number of subtitle tracks

```
var subtitleTracks = YourAVURLAsset.tracks(AVMediaType.subtitle);
var nSubtitleTracks = var subtitleTracks.count;
```

**Note:** *Code is untested so may need to be adjusted a bit but hopefully this gets you going in the right direction*

Comment: thanks for the response , I tried   `let videotrackCount = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).count` but this returns 0

Comment: I tried this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439299/trackswithmediatype-returns-0-tracks-sometimes but no luck